# jqplot: make xaxis label rorate

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I try to make the xaxis label rotate by so far no luck, Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YX9wX/10/

```
xaxis: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
    ticks: jsonColsObj,
    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
    tickOptions: {
      angle: -30,
      fontFamily: 'Arial',
      fontSize: '9pt'
    }
  },
```

As you can see the label 'Test' lie horizontally instead of an angle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed this plugin reference:

```
jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.js
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pabloker/YX9wX/12/

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply, I was tie up with other tasks. Your answer works great. I just want to ask you another question, if I dont want to have xaxis label, so I pass in `['']`, `null` and `''` for the `tick`, but it always show `1` for the x-axis label, do you have any idea how to fix this? Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YX9wX/13/. Method `generateStackedBarCharts(data, label, [''], targetDiv);`, third parameter is my x-axis label. I can make another question if u want.

Comment: I make another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440519/jqplot-how-to-not-render-any-x-axis-label