# jqplot: how to not render any x-axis label

Tags: jquery, jqplot

How can I have so that no xaxis label got render, like

```
xaxis: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
    ticks: jsonColsObj,
    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
    tickOptions: {
      angle: -30,
      fontFamily: 'Arial',
      fontSize: '9pt'
    }
},
```

For `jsonColsObj`, I pass in `['']`, `null` and `''` for the tick, but it always show `1` for the x-axis label, do you have any idea how to fix this?

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YX9wX/13/)

I'm using the method `generateStackedBarCharts(data, label, [''], targetDiv);`, with the third parameter as my x-axis label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the label by using

```
showLabel: false
```

within the `TickOptions` section ... [your updated jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/YX9wX/14/) and [documentation for jqPlot options here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html)